# How to request a particular IP address from the DHCP Server?

Tags: c, dhcp

I'm trying to request a specific IP address from a [DHCP server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol).

My understanding is that I should be able to do this, if the server supports the  DHCP_REQUESTED_IP request in the initial DHCP_DISCOVER message.

Here's the code I have that isn't working:

```
 ip_addr_copy(&dhcp->msg_out->ciaddr , "0xc0a80014" );
 dhcp->msg_out->yiaddr.addr = 0xc0a801e0 ;

 dhcp_option(dhcp, DHCP_OPTION_REQUESTED_IP, 4);
 dhcp_option_long(dhcp, htonl(0xc0a80176));
 dhcp_option_long(dhcp, htonl(0xc0a801e0));
 dhcp_option(dhcp, DHCP_OPTION_SERVER_ID, 4);
 dhcp_option_long(dhcp, htonl(0xc0a80164));
 dhcp_option_long(dhcp, htonl(0xc0a80101));

 dhcp_option(dhcp, DHCP_OPTION_PARAMETER_REQUEST_LIST, 4/*num options*/);
```

Comment: Busybox' dhcp client supports that option, and its source is widely available, so I don't understand your question?

Comment: I need to make a client application which does the above mentioned stuff.(i.e requesting and setting the ip address).I have set the DHCP_REQUESTED_IP option in the dhcp code that you cite at but to no avail.

Comment: The server isn't required to offer the requested address, check [rfc 2131](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2131.txt) : `The client broadcasts a DHCPDISCOVER message on its local physical subnet. The DHCPDISCOVER message MAY include options that suggest values for the network address and lease duration.`.  Note, the rfc says *suggest*

Comment: I think you need to show a piece of code that you have tried, if someone says there is working code, you say you found it and tested and doesn't work that is something to hinge on. Also by "to no avail" you mean you didn't get the IP you wanted or failed to issue the request? It is natural you will not always get requested IP.

Comment: Sorry for the choppy edit there, but as per what @luk32 says, can you give us a bit more to go on?  What is the server you're talking to, how can anyone else reproduce the problem?  Myself I've never heard of asking a DHCP server for a specific IP... and I've written a DHCP server years ago... so this is news to me!  What server are you talking to?  How can anyone reproduce your problem?  Etc.  Welcome to StackOverflow by the way.  :-)

Comment: @luk32 I do not know if anybody has done it.And most people i have asked about have not personally come across this type of a question.So i dint know.If you absolutely know it cannot be done i will go with it.

Comment: @HostileFork Thanks for the answer , but if you have written the DHCP server and if you say that it cannot be done i will welcome it.The Server in question here will be the one running on my dd-wrt router which is in most probabilities DHCP.(udhcpc I saw it after telnetting into my router.) And as far as the reproduction goes you can add the aforementioned lines in the dhcp_discover function in your dhcp.c file which in my case is the client.

Comment: @fvu I cannot find reference to my context here , But as far as i learnt and came across it was written that if you add the aforementioned option in the discover message and the server does not have any problem with that it will happily allocate to you the ip address.Happily here refers if the requested ip address is not already occupied (Which is not by the way in my case.).So theoretically i should get the ip I desire.

Answer (score 1):

As per my assumption when discovery started to `dhcp` at that time you request IP address.
Now,For example.

If using `udhcpc` **(busybox:The udhcp client negotiates a lease with the DHCP server and notifies a set of scripts when a leases is obtained or lost.)*** i discover ip on interface wlan0 then i write first below system call for starting discovery on `wlan0`

```
system("udhcpc -i wlan0")
```

then call

```
 GetIpAddress_system(ipaddress);//for getting ip address
```

so simple code is

```
char ipaddress[16];
system("udhcpc -i wlan0")
GetIpAddress_system(ipaddress);//for getting ip address
printf("\nip address:%s",ipaddress);
```

find source for `GetIpAddress_system()` as below

```
static int GetIpAddress_system(char *myIp)
{
    int retVal=0;
    int size  = 1;
    struct ifreq       *ifr;
    struct ifconf      ifc;
    struct sockaddr_in sa;
    char ip_add[24]={0};
    int serversocket;                        /* Socket */

    #define inaddrr(x) (*(struct in_addr *) &ifr->x[sizeof sa.sin_port])
    #define IFRSIZE   ((int)(size * sizeof (struct ifreq)))
    /* Create socket for receiving  */
    if ((serversocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0){
        printf("socket() failed");fflush(stdout);
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        ifc.ifc_len = IFRSIZE;
        ifc.ifc_req = NULL;
        do
        {
            ++size;
            /* realloc buffer size until no overflow occurs  */
            if (NULL == (ifc.ifc_req = realloc(ifc.ifc_req, IFRSIZE)))
            {
                retVal= -1;
                break;
            }
            ifc.ifc_len = IFRSIZE;
            if (ioctl(serversocket, SIOCGIFCONF, &ifc))
            {
                perror("ioctl SIOCFIFCONF");
                retVal = -1;
                break;
            }
        }while(IFRSIZE <= ifc.ifc_len);

        if(0 == retVal)
        {
            ifr = ifc.ifc_req;
            for (;(char *) ifr < (char *) ifc.ifc_req + ifc.ifc_len; ++ifr)
            {
                if (ifr->ifr_addr.sa_data == (ifr+1)->ifr_addr.sa_data)
                {
                    continue;  /* duplicate, skip it */
                }
                if (ioctl(serversocket, SIOCGIFFLAGS, ifr))
                {
                    continue;  /* failed to get flags, skip it */
                }
                if(strcmp(ifr->ifr_name,"wlan0") == 0)
                {
                    strncpy(ip_add,inet_ntoa(inaddrr(ifr_addr.sa_data)),sizeof(ip_add));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        close(serversocket);
    }

    if(0 == retVal)
    {
        printf("%s\n",ip_add);
        if(myIp)
        {
            memset(myIp,0,15);
            snprintf(myIp,15,"%s",ip_add);
        }
        if(ip_add[0])
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }


    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```